# Using group by in mysql query not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this query which is getting one comment from the wordpress database but it should be getting five results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wpblog_comments.* 
FROM wpblog_comments, wpblog_wti_like_post 
WHERE wpblog_comments.comment_post_ID = 283 
ORDER BY count(wpblog_wti_like_post.id) DESC;
```

Anyone know where im going wrong with it.

Cheers

Comment: The **WHERE** is where I would start ...

Comment: I suspect that you have one row in wpblog_comments that matches your query criteria, and 5 in wpblog_wti_like_post.  However, the SELECT clause only includes fields from wpblog_comments.  Since you are selecting DISTINCT, only one row shows up.  Is that the case?